# RS2008 (not R2) - Hyperlink in a new window

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I have a report in RS2008 (NOT R2) where I need one of the columns to link to a different site.  I can accomplish this by going to Textbox Properties -> Action -> Hyperlink -> Go To URL -> Insert URL formula.

However, this URL by default consumes the parent window. There is a solution whereby you can insert some JavaScript (ex. JavaScript:void(window.open('[URL]','_blank')) into the URL formula and that also works like a charm.

The problem with that is that if the user then subscribes to the report, they get it via email.  Since we use a desktop mail client (Outlook), JavaScript does not work!!!

So, it would be really nice if there was a way I could inject HTML in the cell so that the link works in browsers and desktop mail clients.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typing my question I found the answer, hurrah for ask the duck!

http://dinesql.blogspot.com/2010/05/reporting-services-2008-showing-html.html

Hope this helps the next poor sap that is using RS2008...